# AlertDialog error in android

Tags: android, dialog

Me used the following code to create a AlertDialog.

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
 builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     alert.show();
```

But it shows error on `alert.show()`
The error i got is

```
02-03 11:36:43.204: WARN/dalvikvm(452): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
         02-03 11:36:43.214: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(452): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
         02-03 11:36:43.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(452): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
         02-03 11:36:43.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(452):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:472)
         02-03 11:36:43.234: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(452):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
```

this class is an activity

```
public class HomeTabActivity extends Activity
```

This is HomeTabActivity is one the groupActivity since me using each tap as an activity.
I called this activity like this

```
 View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("hometab", new
                 Intent(this,HomeTabActivity.class)
                 .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
         replaceView(view);
```

What did i miss. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getParent());
```

Answer (score 6):

First line is wrong. When calling it from Activity it should be

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Comment: is true answer!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Activity` methods `onCreateDialog(int id)` and call it with `showDialog(id)`? [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) is good resource about dialogs in android.

Comment: To add more details using onCreateDialog() instead of dialog.show() is better because it does some magic that keeps the dialog on the screen even when the activity is recreated (such as when rotating the screen). But it has nothing to do with your error (see Zelimir answer for that)

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to help him solving current issue. Managing AlertDialog magic related to screen rotation is just a metter of one boolean saved in onSaveInstanceState() and recovered in onCreate().